# Database Relational Algebra: How to find actors who have played in ALL movies produced by "Universal Studios"?

Tags: relational-algebra, relational-division

Given the following relational schemas, where the primary keys are in bold:

`movie(`**`movieName`**`, whenMade);`
`actor(`**`actorName`**`, age);`
`studio(`**`studioName`**`, location, movieName);`
`actsIn(`**`actorName`**`,` **`movieName`**`);`

How do you find the list of actors who have played in EVERY movie produced by "Universal Studios"?

My attempt, where ⋈ is natural join:

```
π actorName ∩ (σ studioName="Universal Studios" studio) ⋈ actsIn
```

Maybe you are supposed to use Cartesian product and/or division.

Comment: This kind of query is usually solved with a division.

Comment: That expression doesn't make sense. Is the ∩ supposed to be there? Why did you write that expression & where is the 1st place you are unsure/stuck? [mre] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the two steps that you should follow:

1. Write an expression to find the names of movies produced by “Universal Studio” (the result is a relation with a single attribute)
2. Divide the relation `actsIn` by the result of the relation obtained at the first step.

This should give you the expected result (i.e. a relation with the actor names that have played in every movie of the “Universal Studio”).